# How to check number of pending messages or all messages are processed or not in ActiveMQ using mule flow

Tags: activemq-classic, mule

I have a requirement to stop the ActiveMQ connector if all messages have been processed in the queue. This needs to be done in Mule flow.

As shown below, I have two connectors one for reading and other for writing on vci.staging.queue. I want to check if all messages are processed in the queue then disable the reader connector.

Below piece of script to use client.request from muleContext using queue name and reader or writer connector is always returning ‘null’ for me.

Is there any way to get number of pending messages in a queue or to check if all messages are processed or not so that connector can be disabled?

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnectorStagingQReaderNormal"
                            brokerURL="${mule.activemq.broker.read.normal.url}" 
                            specification="1.1"
                            maxRedelivery="-1"
                            persistentDelivery="true"
                            numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="${mule.activemq.concurrent.receivers}"
                            connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
                            disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="false">
        </jms:activemq-connector>

<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnectorStagingQWriter"
                            brokerURL="${mule.activemq.broker.write.url}" 
                            specification="1.1"
                            maxRedelivery="-1"
                            persistentDelivery="true"
                            numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="${mule.activemq.concurrent.receivers}"
                            connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
                            disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="false">
        </jms:activemq-connector>


<script:component>
<script:script engine="groovy">
        if(muleContext.getRegistry().lookupConnector('jmsConnectorStagingQReaderNormal').isStarted()) {
            if(muleContext.client.request("jms://vci.staging.queue?connector= jmsConnectorStagingQReaderNormal ", 5000) == null) {
                muleContext.getRegistry().lookupConnector('jmsConnectorStagingQReaderNormal').stop()
             }
        }                               
        return payload
        </script:script>
</script:component>
```

Comment: Can you remove the spaces around `jmsConnectorStagingQReaderNormal` in `"jms://vci.staging.queue?connector= jmsConnectorStagingQReaderNormal "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [QueueBrowser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) to peek into a JMS queue without consuming its messages.

For this:

- Create a custom component,
- Have Spring inject your `jms:activemq-connector` in the component,
- Call `getSession(false, false)` on it to get an active JMS `Session`,
- Call `createBrowser(Queue queue)` on the `Session` (you can get a hold of the `Queue` with `Session.createQueue(..)`.

Comment: I have implemented this logic but somehow enumeration from queue browser doesn’t have any elements.

Comment: Even if the queue is not-empty?